# Android Fragment Navigation Custom Navigation Back Button

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I need to navigate a stack of fragments and I am navigating back using the toolbar back button. Can I override the back button pressed to set a custom animation, for example slide out?

Here is the code for the toolbar.

```
private fun setupToolbar() {
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawer_layout)
    val toolbar = toolbar as Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    val ab: ActionBar? = supportActionBar
    ab?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false) // disable the default title element here (for centered title)
    setupSearchQueryListener()
}
```

Comment: You can do so by overriding onBackPressed in your hosting activity then using an interface as a listener if i understand what you're asking correctly

Comment: Hmm.  seems like the onBackPressed is only activated when I press the "physical" back button on my phone?

Comment: you can create a custom toolbar, register a clickListener with your custom toolbar back button then trigger the interface in your onclick event or just trigger the interface in your current toolbar's back button event. make sense?

Comment: Is it possible to use the default toolbar and in some way access the back button anyway?

Comment: Try overriding onSupportNavigateUp

Comment: It does not work. I'll add some more details to the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your setup code, one more thing is needed:

```
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() 
    }
```

In your fragments, you could do this:

```
    protected lateinit var backPressedCallback: OnBackPressedCallback

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        backPressedCallback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            // your code
        }
    }
```

The above will enable you to intercept back navigation uniformly and execute your code in question (you can even block/unblock it by playing with `backPressedCallback.isEnabled` flag). The above was tested. Speaking of setting navigation animation, I was only playing with xml defined action based animations:

```
        <action
            android:id="@+id/toYourDest"
            app:destination="@+id/yourDest"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/your_slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/your_slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/your_slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/your_slide_out_right" />
```